# How to link and compile using specific library version installed at custom location?

Tags: compilation, linker

I am trying to compile a program which uses GSL, in fact I am already able to compile it successfully on my local machine using

```
g++ -o program program.c prog0.o -L/usr/local/lib -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm
```

My problem is that I need to compile this program on a work machine in a shared system, but I know the program will not compile with an up to date version of GSL, so I need to install and use an older version.
I did this on my own system using the default installation, so the relevant files are located in /usr/local/lib on my local machine, and the compilation works for me with the above command.

But since the work machine is in a shared system, I cannot mess with the default directories, so I installed the correct GSL version on the work machine in my directory under /home/myname/gsl/.
So on the work machine the folder /home/myname/gsl/lib contains the same relevant files as the folder /usr/local/lib on my machine.

Now I did various attempts to try and tell g++ to use this custom installation folder, which I thought would come down to

```
g++ -o program program.c prog0.o -L/home/myname/gsl/lib -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm
```

but no success. No matter what I did g++ always used the GSL version installed on the shared system, even using just

```
g++ -o program program.c prog0.o
```

I only started programming C/C++ not long ago and only know the very basics of how to compile programs, so this linking thing is still always confusing me..
But as far as I can tell -L/dir/ should tell g++ to use the library in /dir/ and -lgsl -lgslcblas are the files which it should look for in that library... ?
But it seems g++ doesn't care what library I tell it here, it always seems to use whatever is in the PATH of the shared work system, which seems to include this up-to-date version of GSL that I cannot use. But I also cannot change the PATH since I only have access to my own subdirectories on the work system..
So how do I tell g++ to ignore the default version of GSL and use the one I installed manually at /home/myname/gsl/ ?

Comment: `g++` is the C++ compiler frontend, but your file uses `.c` which is C normally. Get the languages right , they are different languages! There is no language "C/C++"!

Comment: Have you tried gcc?

Comment: @Olaf err.. artifacts of me getting supplied C programs and not being very fond of C, so I used C++ to extend them and am in the process of getting rid of the C.. currently still a mix of both, but w/e as long as it works I currently have higher priorities. Such as getting this compilation to work.

Comment: @Nguai al a large part of the code is in C++ so I doubt gcc will work

Comment: Try this: -rpath=/home/myname/gsl/lib

Comment: If you compile as C++, it is **not C**! Identical syntax does not imply identical semantics.

Comment: @Nguai with -rpath I only get `g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-rpath=/home/myname/gsl/lib’`

Comment: Try this. Specify path and library like this: g++  -o program program.c prog0.o /home/myname/gsl/lib/libgsl.so /home/myname/gsl/lib/libgslcblas.so  -lm

Comment: @Nguai unfortunately still the same error that comes from using the wrong version. But thanks for trying to help! I suppose there is no way to tell the compiler to "look at this library first"? Or even more extreme to tell the compiler to not look anywhere *but* at the given lib? (though i would probably be stuck at how to link the standard lib then..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the answer, it is actually simple. The problem was just my lack of understanding proper usage of outside libraries and trying to fix the compilation command was the wrong approach.

In the code in program.c, gsl was included with

```
#include <gsl/gsl_blas.h>
```

and so on. Of course, the "<>" directly tell the compiler to look in known include directories, where the up-to-date GSL is installed on the shared system.. So the way to use a custom version was just to instead use

```
#include "/home/myname/gsl/lib/gsl_blas.h"
```

and so on, directly specifying that I want to use my custom installation.
I then compiled with

```
g++ -o program program.c prog0.o /home/myname/gsl/lib/libgsl.so /home/myname/gsl/lib/libgslcblas.so -lm
```

and it compiles successfully.

(This brought up some other unclarities for me, but at least this specific problem is solved.)